# How do I replace double quotes with its escape?

Tags: javascript

```
var string = "{ "Name": ""Jack"" }"
```

I want to replace the double quotes with \" so that the variable becomes a valid JSON.

so, it should end up looking like this:

```
string = "{ "Name": \""Jack"\" }"
```

I know you can use the replace function but I'm not getting it to work.

Comment: escapes bro. escapes. `\"` that allows you to use certain "special" characters.

Comment: bro, care to show me a replace function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put a backslash in front of each double quote that should be escaped.

```
var string = "{\"Name\":\"\\\"Jack\\\"\"}"
```

However, your questions very much looks like an XY problem where you are trying to do something in the completely wrong way! You usually never have to deal with escaping etc. when JSON is involved.

Initially you probably have an object. Let's assume `obj = {Name: "Jack"}`. Now you apparently want to JSON-encode it. In JavaScript you use `JSON.stringify(obj)` for it, in PHP you'd do `json_encode($obj)`. However, if you want to assign this to a JS variable, you can just put the encoded JSON right after `obj =`, like this. If you **really** have to put a JSON *string* somewhere, you can simply run the JSON encoder over the string again (that's how I created the string in this post):

```
JSON.stringify(JSON.stringify({Name: 'Jack'}))
```

Comment: I guess I wasn't clear enough. I need to know how to put this mumble jumble in a replace function.

Comment: Thief, here's the issue. I have a string that comes into a java script function. This string has 1 value with double quotes e.g. "Name": ""Jack"". Inside this function, I do an AJAX call using this JSON "string" ... the problem is, it has the double quotes (so the ajax call is unsuccessful). So where would I do the stringify exactly or would I do this in a different way?

Comment: that sounds like you're building the JSON by string concatenation.  **don't build serialized structure by concatenating.**  make an object and then serialize it, e.g., `JSON.stringify({"Name": variable_containing_name})`